# looper.prepare an ui thread

Tags: android, user-interface, looper

I am trying to use an SDK that seems to need to create a handler into my service.

A error message appeared saying that I can't create handler if the thread has not called `Looper.prepare()`, so I do call `Looper.prepare()` and this problem disappear.
However, this service need to start an activity after a while, and this `Looper.prepare()` seems to be messing with it, as the first UI function crash saying that it cannot be called from a non-ui thread.

I am a bit confused about why this is happening, and the research I made on thread and looper didn't help me. I get why we cannot create a handler if a looper does not exist on the thread, but not why creating a looper prevent me from using the ui thread afterward.

Below my code simplified :

```
public class MyService extends Service implement SDKCallback{

...

void callSDK(){

    Looper.prepare();
    SDK.run(); //Does thing I don't know about
}

@Override
SDKCallback(){

    startActivity(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);

}


}
```

Comment: Can u post the code please ?

Comment: Just did but I'm not sure if it helps. The problem really comes from the interaction between handler; looper and the ui thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to call `Looper.prepare()`. Try this code to create `Handler`,

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) {

    }
};
```

If you put `Looper.prepare()` in your worker thread, it will solve your first crash problem [the thread has not called `Looper.prepare()`]. But its not in UI thread, so you cant start next `Activity`.

What this above code does is, it creates the `Handler` in UI thread. So you can start next `Activity`.

Edit: Try this.

```
@Override
SDKCallback(){

    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MyService.this, MyActivity.class));
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: I can't. I am not the one creating the Handler. The SDK does and I have no access to it's code. Is there a way to change the looper the handler use without accessing it?

Comment: I updated my answer. create handler inside SDKCallback and try. @Laetan

Comment: @DineshBob right answer, only problem is that in the intent this will not work as this will refer to the Handler class, it should be startActivity(new Intent(MyService.this, MyActivity.class);

Comment: yes. i copied the line from question. didnt notice that. thankq :) @varunkr